# problems about Multi-process queue and dictionarie

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I tried to write a program to crack the password of a compressed file, but the efficiency is low, so I decided to use multiple processes to improve efficiency. I use Queue multi-process to store the dictionary password. I want to be a sub-process to find a password, it can shut down all processes, but I do not have a good idea. So I tried the following methods:
1. After I find the password, I write the total number of processes "close" to the queue, and close the process when other processes get "close". This method is very effective, but the queue is FIFO, why just write the queue, other sub-processes can get it? And efficiency is not bad.
2. I used a dictionary inside the Manager, value default is True, if the child process to find the password, the value will be written as False, and then closed to get False after the other processes. This is also feasible, but why spend more time than method one?

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: i just want to know why this FIFO Queue working like this

Comment: you'd better provide a [mcve].